# Explicitly set the order of build targets defined in NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio-2017, target, octopack

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project for building an Azure Function App.  This project contains (amongst others) two NuGet packages - **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** and **OctoPack**.  The packages are referenced in this order by the `.csproj` file for the Project in question.

The `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package contains the target `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild` -

```
<Target Name="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" AfterTargets="Build">...</Target>
```

The `OctoPack` package contains the target `Octopack` -

```
<Target Name="OctoPack" Condition="$(RunOctoPack)">...</Target>
```

When building, it's essential that the `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild` target runs before the `OctoPack` target, otherwise required files are not available in the NuGet package generated by **OctoPack**.

As I can't edit the NuGet packages directly, I'm unable to explicitly state `AfterTarget="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild"` for the `OctoPack` target.  Is there any way I can force the targets to run in the order that I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of a answer, I've come up with a workaround.  Instead of using **OctoPack**, I'm manually generating the NuGet package after the build has completed.

In the **NuSpec** file, I've added a couple of tokens for `%Configuration%` and `%Version%` so that I can choose the files to package based on the configuration, and obviously customise the version.

Here's what I'm doing - obviously I'm making `$version` before these lines.

```
$dir = (Get-Location).Path
& D:\nuget\4.4.1\nuget.exe pack $dir\AzureFunction\AzureFunction.nuspec -BasePath $dir\AzureFunction -Properties "Configuration=Release;Version=$version"
```